# I get the typeerror while executing the following program

Tags: python, spotipy

```
def get_playlist_tracks(username, playlist_id):
    results = sp.user_playlist_tracks(username,playlist_id)
    playlist_items = results['items']
    uris = []

    while results['next']:
        results = sp.next(results)
        playlist_items.append(results['items'])

    for item in playlist_items:
        track_uri = item["track"]["uri"]
        uris.append(track_uri)
    return uris

get_playlist_tracks('iKetu', '7h10RuUjKqfqwWibESmwy1')

print(uris)
```

The Output I get is

```
PS C:\Users\iketu\Music\Elite\Album Artworks> & C:/Users/iketu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/iketu/Music/Elite/Album Artworks/getAlbumArt.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/iketu/Music/Elite/Album Artworks/getAlbumArt.py", line 27, in <module>
    get_playlist_tracks('iKetu', '7h10RuUjKqfqwWibESmwy1')
  File "c:/Users/iketu/Music/Elite/Album Artworks/getAlbumArt.py", line 23, in get_playlist_tracks
    track_uri = item["track"]["uri"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: We can't see the API response so it's not possible to debug this. I'd _guess_ that it needs to be `track_uri = item["track"][0]["uri"]` like the bajillion other JSON questions but you haven't given a [mcve] so that could well be a broken solution

Comment: what is the type for ```item``` in the for loop?   that traceback could either be complaining about "track"  or "uri".

Comment: Now it says Keyerror 0

Comment: Well then it's really borked because you can't get a `KeyError` for a list, so you definitely need to give an MCVE like I asked. I can't debug something I can't see

Comment: Still suprised to see how many (beginner) programmers won't use the built-in pdb.set_trace() to figure out what a value is and why their programs crash. I honoustly think it would save 50% of these kind of questions.